# ASP.Net MVC4 checkboxfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have this 
viewmodel

```
public class Group
{
    public int intGroup { get; set; }
    public bool bCheck { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupDetail>  GroupDetail { get; set; }
}

public class GroupDetail 
{

    public int intGroupDetail { get; set; } 

}
```

i know the strongly type method to bind data into checkboxfor is like this

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.bCheck)
```

Now my problem is if i like to bind the checkbox when there is a record in my viewmodel GroupDetail , how could i bind this? and there is possible no data in the GroupDetail.

Comment: Please read over your question and make it more understandable.  Your view model does not implement the property you appear to be trying to bind, nor does your model appear to support anything that could be termed a record.

Comment: How is GroupDetail related to the checkbox?

Comment: Please use PartialView for bind the 'GroupDetail' collection.